# How to call web API from an http client using a small timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working with two web API projects that get communicated. The first web API calls the second one using an HttpClient class.

What I would like to do is to set a short timeout (500 ms) when I call the second web API, and if I don't get response in that time, just to skip the next lines that process the result in the client, but continue processing the request at server side(second API).

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
       client.Timeout = this.Timeout; // (500ms)
       HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(EndPoint, PostData).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
        }
        else
        {
                 throw new CustomException()
        }

 }
```

It works in the first API side, however in the second API(server), I get the following exceptions:

```
 "A task was canceled."
 "The operation was cancelled."
 at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
 at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
```

I think it is caused by the small timeout of the call, that ends when the second API is still processing the result.

How could I avoid this behaviour in the second API and continue processing the request ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior. When you set a timeout and the call does not respond in that amount of time, the task is canceled and that exception is thrown.

And by the way, do not use `.Result`. That will cause blocking. Mark your method `async` and use `await`.

The whole thing should look something like this:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.Timeout = this.Timeout; // (500ms)
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(EndPoint, PostData);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new CustomException()
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // request did not complete in 500ms.
        return null; // or something else to indicate no data, move on
    }
 }
```

Comment: In this case, I'll need to continue processing the call in the second web API  to store the result in a cache/database result. How could I let it continue processing even if the task was cancelled?

Comment: You didn't post the whole method, but I assume that since you're returning the result when the call succeeds, the additional processing is happening somewhere else? If so you could just return null from the catch block, or some other value to signal to the caller that it didn't get results fast enough.

Comment: The method displayed is at the first API side, it is the client calling to second API. If it doesn't get results I just skip the process, But what I mean is I need that second API continue processing the call even if it was cancelled by the client. Second API, server, needs to complete the task and store it in a cache, independently client timeout expired. I get the exceptions in the second API, server side, not client(first API) side.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. Had no idea the "continued processing" is occurring in the 2nd API. To my knowledge the server should have no idea that the client canceled the request. If you're able to repro this in your dev environment, I'd say set a breakpoint in the 2nd API and inspect what's happening. I think something else is in play here.